# How to remove the requirement for administrator permission from a file in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-explorer, ntfs

I have recently launched TrueCrypt in Administrator Mode and created a encryped file container. Now when I want to move the file, rename the file or do anything it requires me to approve the action with administrator access instead of just clicking OK:

[image]

No matter how I setup the permissions on this file, this keeps happening. Other files created in non-administrator mode don't require approval for everything? How can I "Unblock" this file? (So I don't have to click continue on every thing I do! :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the file accesible for other users you need to update the integrity level of the file.

This can be done by using icacls.exe in the system32 folder but this reg file will add a context menu which allows setting the level:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\setintegritylevel]
"SubCommands"="setintegritylevellow;setintegritylevelmedium;setintegritylevelhigh;"
"MUIVerb"="Set Integrity Level"
"Position"="-"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\setintegritylevel]
"SubCommands"="setintegritylevellow;setintegritylevelmedium;setintegritylevelhigh;"
"MUIVerb"="Set Integrity Level"
"Position"="-"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevelhigh]
@="High"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevelhigh\command]
@="icaclsadmin.exe \"%1\" /setintegritylevel H"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevellow]
@="Low"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevellow\command]
@="icaclsadmin.exe \"%1\" /setintegritylevel L"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevelmedium]
@="Medium"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\setintegritylevelmedium\command]
@="icaclsadmin.exe \"%1\" /setintegritylevel M"
```

To make this work you need to make a copy of the file "icacls.exe" and name it "icaclsadmin.exe", right click the new .exe and go to compatibility tab. Select "Run as Administrator" (for all users) and you are done :)

Comment: Do you know how this could be achieved at the command line?

Comment: More accurately (I see how your menu items work, now) which value would remove the requirement for elevation on a given folder? High or Low?

Comment: Medium or Low would allow "more access", The higher the more restricted.